# .sleep is not a member of Thread?

Tags: scala

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_102).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> Thread.currentThread.sleep(1000)
<console>:12: error: value sleep is not a member of Thread
   Thread.currentThread.sleep(1000)
                        ^

scala>
```

Huh?

```
scala> Thread.currentThread.getClass.getMethods.filter(_.getName == "sleep").last.invoke(Thread.currentThread, new java.lang.Long(1000))

res2: Object = null // after a second-long delay. Duh
```

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread.sleep() is a static method.

Try this:

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Keep in mind this is a Java class. In Java, things work a bit differently, there are static and instance methods. Static methods do not belong to an instance, you can call them without a containing object.

Comment: `"%d".format(1)` actually works great (in scala, but not in java), so, to say that "static methods do not belong to an instance", isn't exactly correct. 
The actual thing is that scala interprets static method calls as if you wanted to pass the lhs into the method as the first argument, so `"%d".format(1)` becomes `String.format("%d", 1)` and works, and `thread.sleep(1000)` becomes `Thread.sleep(thread, 1000)` and (of course) fails.

Comment: @Dima `"%d".format(1)` does not get converted to `String.format("%d", 1)`. It gets converted to `new StringOps("%d").format(1)` through implicit conversions. `thread.sleep(1000)` doesn't get converted to anything, it just fails because there's no instance method `sleep` and no implicit conversion to something that has one. The statement "Static methods do not belong to an instance" is correct.